# R Shiny DataTables replace numeric with string and sort as being less than numeric values

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, natural-sort

In a Shiny app I have a column of numbers in a `datatable` where for security reasons some values have been suppressed and we want to replace those with a specific string, which here I will call `"my_string"`. When sorting on this column these suppressed values need to sort as though they are *less than* all actual numbers. In this column all values are positive, except for the suppressed values which have been coded as `-1`.

I've tried recoding the `-1` as `"my_string"` (which coerces the column to `character`) and using the [`natural` plug-in](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/plugins.html) to sort the character-coded numerics correctly, but `"my_string"` is being sorted as though it is greater than all of the numeric values.

Another possible way to handle this might be to use a `JavaScript` callback to replace the `-1` with the string, but I don't know how to write that script and properly add it to the `datatable`.

Here is my attempt using the `natural` plug-in. If it was working like I want, the line with "my_string" would be at the bottom of the list instead of the top.

```
# Example data, representing how the data comes to me
my_mtcars <- mtcars[1:6, 1:4]
my_mtcars[1, 4] <- -1

# Here I am recoding the -1
my_mtcars[my_mtcars == -1] <- 'my_string'

# This is our demo app.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput('example')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$example <- renderDataTable(
    my_mtcars,
    server = FALSE,
    plugins = 'natural',
    options = list(columnDefs = list(list(type = 'natural', targets = '_all')))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably easier with a custom formatter / column render function.

See Column Rendering in the DT docs: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

And the DataTables docs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars[1:6, 1:4]
my_mtcars[1, 4] <- -1

formatSuppressedValues <- JS("
  function(data, type) {
    if (type !== 'display') return data;
    if (data !== -1) return data;
    return 'my_string';
  }
")

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('example')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$example <- DT::renderDataTable(
    my_mtcars,
    server = FALSE,
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(
        targets = '_all',
        render = formatSuppressedValues
      ))
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It is also very helpful to see how the general datatables documentation maps to the R `DT` context. A note for future visitors - I had included `server = FALSE` in my example only because the `natural` plug-in requires it, it is not actually necessary for this solution.